# Using thread to slow down the loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, loops

I am new with C#. I am running a loop to send emails to subscribed users. I need to slow down the loop because I only want to send 10 email/second. Is using Thread.sleep good way to slow down the loop? please see code below.

```
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

                //send email code here
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: I hope your not misusing that to spread spam mails.

Comment: nope. i will be sending weekly emails to subscribed users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you have a [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) that fires up every second and sends *up to* ten messages from your message queue every second.

This way you really do have complete control over the process and are not guessing about speed/timings of your email sender.

Perhaps something like this:

```
public class EmailSender
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new Timer(1000);

    public EmailSender()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) => SendEmail();
    }

    public void StartSender()
    {
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void SendEmail()
    {
        // you *may* want to stop your timer here in case the send of the ten overruns 1s.
        _timer.Enabled = false;

        // code here to send UP TO ten emails

        // re-enable timer, if you stopped it above.
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

In short - no - your original approach is not good.

- How do you know how long to make it sleep for to get 10 messages sent?
- What happens if the machine is running slowly anyway?
- What happens if you deploy to a faster machine?
- etc..

Comment: I think what he wants is just the slowdown so he doesn't get rejected by the mail server (my guess).

Answer (score 2):

If that is a GUI application you should use a timer to work through a `Queue`. In a singlethreaded console application that may be ok. If your code is in a separate thread `Thread.Sleep` is ok.

I suggest you to not block the reader too long. But we don't see whats behind the reader.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using Thread.sleep good way to slow down the loop?

Huh, what, no!

> I need to slow down the loop because I only want to send 10 email/second

If that's your spec, then write code that obeys that spec! Sleep as you are using it doesn't ensure that spec. Use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) that fires once a second and sends at most ten emails, or write a queue that guarantees it only serves ten items per second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but what is the type of rdr? If it is SqlDataReader or some other reference to external data(file, database, network and etc.), better to fetch all data first than to keep rdr open for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any problem in the approach defined by you, at least looking on the question provided. 
I immagine you send 10 mails, and after wait for a while so they go out from outbox, for some reason.